# Header always shows in android-pulltorefresh when customize

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, custom-widgets

I was trying to customize [android-pulltorefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) library developed by Johan Nilson. I wanna use my own adapter rather than a String array. I was able to complete almost every thing but the pull to refresh header is always visible. (see the image) I want it to visible only when I pull the listview like it does with the demo app. I compared my code with the demo but I couldn't find any difference between them which effect layout.

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in onRefreshComplete() in PullToRefreshListView,tried the code below when you complete your actions:

```
setSelection(1);
```